# Multiply two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which I want to multiply and get the final sum. First one is fixed but the second one could have missing elements. For example:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(1, 3, 5);
```

Lets say I've got missing elements `$array2[1]` and `$array2[3]`. I want to be able to multiply and sum up the rest as:

```
$sum = array_sum($array1[0] * $array2[0] + $array1[1] * $array2[1] + $array1[2] * $array2[2] + $array1[3] * $array2[3] + $array1[4] + $array2[5]);
```

Length of arrays may also vary so can't do it the way I've written it above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try getting the length of the shortest array, then loop that many times.

Comment: @pendo Already tried but indexes wouldn't match and I want to multiply each element by it corresponding one.

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question, but you implicitly assign the value `1` to missing elements. Why not use that in your loop?

Comment: how to know the key of th missing element?

Comment: See my answer, I cannot put that in a comment.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware because I don't know which element of the second array may be missing. It comes as I have shown in the example above (not specifying which element is 0),

Comment: If you don't know which key is missing. How do your know wichi element multipyl which element??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete the array2 missing values as 1, then make the two array have the same length.

```
$missingKeys = [1,3];
foreach($missingKeys as $k)
{
  $array2[$k] = 1;
}
$sum = 0;
foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
{
  $sum += $v * $array1[$k];
}
```

Comment: That could work for me, I just need to figure out which elements are missing. One correction, though. I wouldn't assign missing value as one because that would contribute to the sum whereas I don't want to keep the value from the first array, corresponding to the value of the 2nd array's element.

Comment: glad it can helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, and your looking for array multiplication, you could use 2 for loops, iterating one of them and multiplying. Your probably looking for something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++) {
        $sum += $array1[$i] * $array2[$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as shown in the question. This multiplies all elements for array 1 with all from array 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't use my own advise, but I think this might work?

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value)
{
  if (isset($array2[$index])) $total += $value*$array2[$index];
                         else $total += $value;
}
echo $total;
```

The assumption is that all elements of `$array2` are present in `$array1`, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: Tried that too but if the length of the first array changes, the result also changes.

Comment: Of course it will, if you add elements, and you change the elements, the sum will also change.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question that the first array is leading (has all the indexes) you only need to iterate over it and eventually multiply with the value from the second array or one:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $sum += $v * ($array2[$k] ?? 1);
}
```

Different to the accepted answer, there is no need to manipulate the second array.